# NASM to GAS: Calling equ'd symbols

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler

I have some NASM files which have a line:

```
%INCLUDE "bmdev.asm"
```

The `bmdev.asm` file has equ directives such as:

```
b_print_newline         equ 0x0000000000100040
```

The files which include `bmdev.asm` then are able to call those items. I.e.

```
call b_print_newline
```

Is there a way to convert this to GAS? When I try to do the direct translation, i.e.

```
.set b_print_newline , 0x100040

call b_print_string
```

it doesn't appear to disassemble to the right thing:

```
callq  *0x100040
```

The NASM call disassembles to:

```
callq  0xfffffffffff00040
```

The goal here is to generate binaries for [BareMetal OS](http://www.returninfinity.com/baremetal.html) via GAS instead of NASM.

The full disassembly of the binary which works:

```
$ objdump -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64 test-nl.app 

test-nl.app:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <.data>:
   0:   e8 3b 00 f0 ff          callq  0xfffffffffff00040
   5:   c3                      retq
```

The full disassembly of the binary which doesn't work:

```
$ objdump -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64 test-nl-a.app 

test-nl-a.app:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <.data>:
   0:   ff 14 25 40 00 10 00    callq  *0x100040
   7:   c3                      retq
```

I've posted a (hopefully) clearer version of this question. Closing this one.

Comment: It might help if you could show the bytes (in hex) they assemble to.

Comment: @user786653 I updated the question with the full disassembly info.

Comment: It's working fine for me (after I changed `b_print_string` to 0x100040). `call b_print_string` produces your correct binary, but `call *b_print_string` produces your incorrect binary. Maybe it's not in the code, but in your arguments while compiling?

Comment: I updated the question to be a bit more consistent. The first part mentioned b_print_string and later I used b_print_newline. I updated everything to be in terms of b_print_newline. The issue is basically the same though.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I'm using the following to assemble and link: `as -o test-nl-a.o test-nl-a.s && ld -Ttext 200000 --oformat binary -o test-nl-a.app test-nl-a.o`

Comment: I put out a [new version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838552/calling-equd-symbols-in-gas) of this question which is more explicit in what I'm assembling and disassembling. Hopefully it's a little more clear. Maybe I should close this one?

Comment: It would be better to edit this question instead of adding a new one, since this question has already had some activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I brought this issue up](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2011-07/msg00262.html) on the binutils mailing list. It appears to be a bug. [It was suggested that I file a bug report](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2011-07/msg00277.html) and [I've done so](http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13046).

A [fix](http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2011-08/msg00006.html) has been checked in to the binutils tree.

Comment: Glad you got an answer. That also explains why I couldn't get it working :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems kind of odd that it should be so difficult to get AS to generate a relative call, perhaps someone smarter can jump in.

Anyway, doing:

```
.set b_print_newline, 0x100040
call b_print_newline
```

results in (as you noticed) AS generating an indirect jump.

You can fake it on your own using the [`.` (dot)](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/as/Dot.html#Dot) pseudo-variable:

```
call b_print_newline - .
```

Or you can use the linker (command line or script as you wish) to define symbols with the correct names, in which case the code gets compiled as you wish.

```
$ cat test.S
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    call b_print_newline
    ret
$ as --64 -o test.o test.S
$ ld --defsym b_print_newline=0x100040 -Ttext 200000 --oformat binary -o test.bin test.o
$ objdump -D -b binary -m i386:x86-64 test.bin
test.bin:     file format binary

Disassembly of section .data:

0000000000000000 <.data>:
   0:   e8 3b 00 f0 ff          callq  0xfffffffffff00040
   5:   c3                      retq
```

There is probably a way to make it work without using the linker to define symbols, but I haven't been able to find a way.

Comment: Good tips as usual. Thanks @user786653!